# How to use ES6 modules while creating jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, jquery-plugins

I am creating a jQuery Plugin for building a form builder. The code is going to be very lengthy. I don't wanna keep everything in just one file.
To achieve this I am trying to break everything into ES6 modules but JS is throwing a Syntax error.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
>
> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).formBuilder is not a function

Here's my code:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Form Builder</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/3.0.1/mustache.min.js"></script>

  <!-- <script src="functions.js"></script> -->
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="form-builder"></div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#form-builder").formBuilder();
</script>
```

**index.js**

```
import formBuilder from './functions.js'

(function($){
    $.fn.formBuilder = function(){
        formBuilder()
    }
}(jQuery))
```

**functions.js**

```
export default function formBuilder(){
    $.get('template.mst', function(template) {
            let rendered = Mustache.render(template, fieldsData);
            $('#form-builder').html(rendered);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to make two changes to get your code to run (in Chrome/Firefox):

First, from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

> The import statement cannot be used in embedded scripts unless such script has a type="module".

This is a little misleading: "embedded script" sounds like it wouldn't include a `src=` script...but in practice it doesn't seem to work without it.

```
<script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
```

Second, module scripts are lazy-loaded, which means your final `script` tag will be executed before `index.js` is actually loaded/parsed. You can change this by using the jQuery `ready` callback.

```
<script>
  $(() => {
    $("#form-builder").formBuilder();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I knew your first point that I need to use type='module' to get in work. but I have seen many jquery plugins which are using ES6 modules but we just import them without specifying this "type" attribute. How they do this>

Comment: Is it possible they are being transpiled via babel/webpack? That's a fairly common technique: write the module using es6, but then transpile/pack/minify the production code.

Comment: @David784 How would a boilerplate of such a ES6 jQuery plugin look like? Does the plugin declare `jquery` as a `peer dependency` in its `package.json`?

Comment: @tonix Bit much for a comment in another question, but basically: If you're asking how to write a browser `script type=module`, I'd start [here](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/). If you're asking about babel, I'd recommend googling "babel es6 module" and start there. Best way to do it is just to get started and if you run into a specific problem you can't solve, post a new question with [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).